# How to Hide Title bar from VLC Media Player (VLC Direct 3d output)using LIBVLC in vc++

Tags: libvlc

I am using libvlc in vc++.I want to hide the title bar from VLC Output Window(VLC 3D Direct OUTPUT). Can we hide or remove this title bar?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var handle in EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id))
{
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(1000);
    SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXT, message.Capacity, message);
    if (message.ToString().Equals("VLC (Direct3D11 output)"))
    {
        var style = (SetWindowLongFlags)GetWindowLong(handle, WindowLongIndexFlags.GWL_STYLE);

        style &= ~SetWindowLongFlags.WS_BORDER;

        SetWindowLong(handle, WindowLongIndexFlags.GWL_STYLE, style);
    }
}
```